# onclick() and onblur() never work in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, onclick, onblur

I'm using javacsript functions onclick and onblur on text area they are working fine in Firefox but never work in IE8. I need to call javascript function to be called on every key press. 
What is the solution?

```
<textarea name="txtClassifiedText" rows="5" cols="40" id="txtClassifiedText" onblur="recalc()" onkeypress="recalc()" onclick="this.value='';">Enter your classified text here (MAX 40 words)*</textarea>

<script>function recalc() {
        alert('hi');
    }</script>
```

There's no javascript error in IE8 or FF

Comment: @hotcoder: You're going to have to provide some code--those events should work in IE8.

Comment: Whats your code? I suggest you use jQuery, then it'll work across all browsers

Comment: how is it possible? please clarify your question and provide more detail so that some solution can be posted, normally this don't happen, may be there is some other thing causing that function not calling or you are not checking clearly whether function is being called or not, problem will not be of onclick and onblur e.t.c.

Comment: @hotcoder: it seems strange because there don't seem to be any problem with Javascript code, however I am not familiar with asp code. But it seems to be fine but if you can post ouput (js/html code) than I may confirm

Comment: Have you considered just using an event handle (ie: element.onblur) instead of what you're currently using? I get a "recalc is not defined" error using your code.

Comment: I've extracted HTML code from page source. I want recalc() function to be called on every key press.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe "recalc" might be a protected word.  Rename your function something like "booger" and retest.  Good luck!

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=vs.85).aspx

> The recalc method allows authors to explicitly cause the values of dynamic properties to be updated.

Comment: Thanks Hufford, you're great!

Comment: It's not a global symbol however, as far as I can tell. It's a property of "document."